# funcion que escuche lo que presiona el usuario

Tags: angular

no se si anteriormente han planteado esta interrogante, quisiera crear una funcion tipo eventListener, en la cual en background este "escuchando" lo que el usuario esta presionando en el teclado, de manera tal que al presionar "F5", pueda manipular una serie de acciones para evitar que se actualice la pagina, OJO sin un input, que en cualquier ubicacion de la pagina detecte lo que presiona, cabe destacar que trabajo con bootstrap y angular js

Answer (score 2):

Agrega el evento `keyup` al objeto `window` utilizando `addEventListener`

```
window.addEvenListener("keyup",function(e){
   console.log("Se presiono la tecla con el id:" + e.which);
});
```

Asi podras saber que tecla presiono el usuario de manera global.

Comment: perfecto amigo sin embargo, cuando se presiona la tecla F5 es como una tecla reservada para el navegador y no registra esa tecla, actualiza la pagina de una vez, sin embargo este evento me es util gracias

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo esta podría ser una opción para ti:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
        // 116 => codigo de la tecla f5
        if (e.keyCode === 116) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer al cargar la pagina:

```
<body>  
<script type = "text/javascript">  
    window.onload = function () {  
        document.onkeydown = function (e) {  
            return (e.which || e.keyCode) != 116;  
        };  
    }  
</script>  
    <h1>  
        Pagina sin recarga
    </h1>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a las respuestas que ya te dieron, podrías implementer

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'En verdad quieres salir de mi sitio?';
}
```